# Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph with mutually exclusive edges

Tags: graph, time-complexity

**Problem**

I want to solve *Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph Problem* **where some edges are mutually exclusive**.

**Example**

Left vertices: *a,b,c*

Right vertices: *x,y,z*

Edges: *(a,x), (a,y), (b,z), (c,y)*

Exlusive pairs: *(b,z)* and *(c,y)*

Answer: *no perfect matching*

**Question**

Is the problem in *P* or *NP*?

**Solution Attempts**

I know that *Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph Problem* is in *P*. But I cannot find a polynomial-time algorithms for the above version of this problem. I have also tried proving that it is *NP*, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by edges being "mutually exclusive" that they don't share a vertex, then the problem you described is a subset of the general *Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph Problem*.

Also try to be more specific with the terms P and NP. P is a subset of NP. Therefore the
*Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph Problem* is also in NP, because it is in P. Something different, what you maybe meant is [NP-hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness). This basicially means "at least as hard as every problem in NP".

Your question should thus be: "Is the problem in P?", because if we had a solution, we could check it easily, thus it is in NP. The property that we can check it in polynomial time is actually the definition of [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)).

And like I said, from my understanding your problem is only a subset of the problem, thus also in P.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is NP-complete. First, let's define the problem formally.

**Perfect Matching with forbidden edge pairs**

**Given**: a bipartite graph (U,V,E) and a set of pairs of edges F = {{e_1,f_1}, ...,{e_s,f_s}}, called the forbidden edge pairs.

**Question:** is there a perfect matching M such that no forbidden edge pair is a subset of M?

This is NP-complete, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a reference for it. NP-completeness follows from a rather simple reduction from 3-SAT:

**Theorem**. Perfect matching with forbidden edge pairs is NP-complete.

**Proof**. We will reduce from 3-SAT. Every clause C will become a "right" vertex. Every *occurrence* of a variable will become a left vertex. For example, the two clauses

C = (x, y, -z) and  D= (-x, u, y)

will produce 6 left vertices: x_C, y_C, z_C, x_D, u_D, y_D. We have m right nodes and 3m left nodes.

The edges: connect every left vertex u_C to the clause C. Choosing (u_C,C) to be in the matching "means" using u to satisfy clause C.

The forbidden pairs: if x in C and -x in D then make {(x_C,C), (x_D,D)} a forbidden pair; note that x cannot be "used" to satisfy both C and D.

Now from a satisfying assignment we can easily create a feasible matching that matches all clause nodes; conversely, from such a matching we can construct a satisfying assignment.

To make satisfying assignments correspond to *perfect matchings*, we add 2m "garbage collection vertices" on the right side, connect all left vertices to all garbage collection vertices and make nothing forbidden there.